# clean-css TypeError cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: gulp-uglify, gulp-minify-css, clean-css, gulp-clean-css

I am trying to minify my code and i always get this error when it runs clean-css.

```
/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/selectors/extractor.js:66
  return name.replace(/^\-\w+\-/, '').match(/([a-zA-Z]+)/)[0].toLowerCase();
                                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at findNameRoot (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/selectors/extractor.js:66:59)
    at extract (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/selectors/extractor.js:36:9)
    at restructure (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/selectors/restructure.js:297:22)
    at optimize (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/selectors/advanced.js:71:5)
    at minify (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/clean.js:228:5)
    at whenSourceMapReady (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/clean.js:135:7)
    at Object.whenDone (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/clean.js:155:14)
    at processNext (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/imports/inliner.js:105:13)
    at importFrom (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/imports/inliner.js:79:10)
    at ImportInliner.process (/home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/imports/inliner.js:38:10)
Error: Hook failed with error code 8: /home/k1ngsley/Projects/mobile_rea/partners-mobile-app/hooks/after_prepare/070_uglify.js
    at /home/k1ngsley/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/hooks/HooksRunner.js:195:23
    at _rejected (/home/k1ngsley/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
    at /home/k1ngsley/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (/home/k1ngsley/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:1035:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/k1ngsley/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:741:41)
    at /home/k1ngsley/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/home/k1ngsley/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

I have read different posts that says remove commented lines etc but all hasnt worked out for me.

Any one has any other ideas or ways to solve this issue

Comment: FYI gulp-minify-css has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) in favor of [gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css)

Comment: @Kingsley Simon:  I`m having same problem now can you please tell me how did you resolve it?         aprreciated!

Comment: @shireefkhatab have u solved this?

Comment: sorry, i had to change my code and use useref insrtead            /* useref */
 gulp.task('useref', ['clean'], function(){
  return gulp.src(paths.html)
  .pipe(useref())
  .pipe(gulpIf('*.html',htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true})))
  .pipe(gulpIf('*.js', uglify(), jshint() ))
  .pipe(gulpIf('*.css', cssnano() ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
 });

Comment: You should answer you own question if you solved the issue yourself. Having a similar error now and not quite sure how you said you solved it now..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [min.css](https://w3core.github.io/min.css/) utility that is more fastest and fault-tolerance.

Comment: How can i include min.css inside the gulp / grunt file please?